# ion-content becomes very rigid on scroll

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created a web app using ionic framework and everything is working fine but sometimes when I scroll through the ion-content then the scroll gets stuck for sometime and works after a few seconds again, if I use jsscrolling then it does not get stuck but it does not scrolls smoothly, it only scrolls till the user drags the content and becomes very rigid.

Answer (score 0):

try after adding overflow-scroll="true" to the ion content

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
```